# Finding numbers in regex (Javascript)

Tags: javascript, regex

This is a weird question, but bear with me...

So, I'm messing around with RegEx: I have the following code and it works fine if the inputText var contains a comma, however If I change it to "99 x icecream, each £99" it does not work...  (i.e. it alerts null)

```
var inputText ="99, icecream, each £99";  // expensive ice cream

var inputText = inputText.toString(); // this was done because I though if I started a string with a number js might do that weird conversion stuff it does, but I don't need it right?

var qXpe = inputText.match(/(\d{1,3})(,|[ x ]?) (\w+), each ([£]\d+[.]?\d{0,2})/g);

alert(qXpe);
```

I want to find sentences which are structured `quantity, product, £price` or `quantity x product, £price`, the current regex works for the former.

So this regex returns `99, icecream, each £99` but `null` for `99 x icecream, each £99`

Can anyone hazard a guess as to why this does not work? Merci.

Comment: Could we see what results you get out of your current regex, and what you _want_ to get out?

Comment: I want to find sentences which are structured `quantity, product, £price` or `quantity x product, £price`, the current regex works for the former.

Comment: Edited so it explains it better.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The number should be followed by a space when it's not followed by a comma but your regex doesn't reflect that, cause `[ x ]?` means either a space or an x, optionally. Maybe you want `( x )?`

Comment: Thank you, you were correct! I've added a space character after the number `(\d{1,3}\s?) ...etc`, it seems to work now

Answer (score 0):

try:

```
(\d+)(?:, | x )(\w+), £(\d+)
```

you can use [rubular](http://rubular.com) to test your RegEx in real time. Enjoy

Comment: Can I ask, what does the : mean in this context?

Comment: the ?: is a lookahead prefix that doesn't capture the , or the x like (, | x ) would. So that your returned structure only has the useful parts you want/need. So the captured items are: 

[1] quantity,
[2] product,
[3] price

Comment: I write with it a lot to ensure structure in the input text. So once you start getting longer strings to parse, you eventually want to separat your data in some way with special characters, and this helps in certain cases. Look at http://www.ruby-doc.org/docs/ProgrammingRuby/html/language.html#UJ for regex rules

Comment: That looks like a non-capturing group to me.

Comment: right. got it confused with the zero-width positive lookahead for a sec. Still serves its purpose.

Comment: rubular tests **Ruby** regexes, which aren't necessarily the same flavour as JavaScript regexes. For those, try [RegexPal](http://regexpal.com/) (among others. there are lots of regex testers out there) I don't know how similar Ruby and JS regexes are, but I never trust any two are exactly the same.